# NSString - How get a part of String surrounded by curly braces

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

My response will be the following format : `{group} community announced: {announcement}`.

Based upon the text inside the `{}`i have to  query a dictionary. I tried using

```
componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"{}"]
```

but it is returning lot of details :

```
(
    "",
    group,
    " community announced: ",
    announcement,
    ""
)
```

So how can I exactly get the characters inside `{}` in an array .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSString *string = @"{group} community announced: {announcement}";

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *pattern = @"\\{((.|\n)*?)\\}";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if (!error)
{
    NSArray *allMatches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in allMatches)
    {
        NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
        NSString *foundString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(matchRange.location+1, matchRange.length-2)];
        [array addObject:foundString];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);
```

With output:

> Array: (
>       group,
>       announcement )

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this nested method call

```
NSString *myString = @"{group} community announced: {announcement}";

[self logTheSplittedString:myString];

- (void)logTheSplittedString:(NSString *)targetString
{
    NSRange start = [targetString rangeOfString:@"{"];
    NSRange end = [targetString rangeOfString:@"}"];

    NSString *betweenBraces1 = @"";

    if (start.location != NSNotFound && end.location != NSNotFound && end.location > start.location)
    {
        betweenBraces1 = [targetString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location+1, end.location-(start.location+1))];
        NSLog(@"%@",betweenBraces1);
    }

    targetString = [targetString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",betweenBraces1] withString:@""];

    NSRange startNext = [targetString rangeOfString:@"{"];
    NSRange endNext = [targetString rangeOfString:@"}"];

    if (startNext.length != 0 && endNext.length != 0)
    {
        [self logTheSplittedString:targetString];
    }
}
```

**output**

> group
>   announcement

Comment: this gives me output 'group' what about my 'announcement'

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find string in between '{text}'
Refer following code

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"{(.*)}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:responceString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [responceString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
        // detect
        NSString *strFind1 = [responceString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
        //log
        NSLog(@"%@",strFind1);
    }];
```

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_handler", referenced from: when running your code